# Plugin add options to entry edition

Tags: plugin-development, entry, events, hook

What I'm trying to do is add two checkbox in the entry edition page, just under the dates or special notes, somewhere here :
[image]

Then if the checkbox is checked, I check it with an event and perform an action. But I dont know how to display my two checkboxes, I know it's all about the hook but I can't find the one.

Any advices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the way lurking into source code. You can see a

```
{# Give plugins a chance to add other panes here #}
{% hook "cp.entries.edit.right-pane" %}
```

Even though this hook is not listed in official documentation, you can access using the `craft()->on()` syntax, so I did this inside my plugin class :

```
public function init() {

    parent::init();

    craft()->templates->hook('cp.entries.edit.right-pane', function(&$context) {

        // do stuff here
    });
}
```